# Oracle PL/SQL How to rollback the newly inserted row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace trigger trig_redeem_coffee
before insert
on buycoffee
for each row
declare
CID int;
customerPoint float;
pointNeeded float;
begin
    select customer_id into CID
    from purchase
    where purchase_id = :new.purchase_id;
    select total_points into customerPoint
    from customer
    where customer_id = CID;
    pro_get_redeem_point (:new.coffee_ID, :new.redeem_quantity, pointNeeded);
    if pointNeeded>customerPoint
    then
        rollback;
    else
        pointNeeded := -1*pointNeeded;
        pro_update_point(CID, pointNeeded);
        end if;
    commit;
end;
/
```

The trigger can be successfully created, but when I insert into buycoffee table(it will meet the condition that pointNeeded>customerPoint), it returns an error that it cannot rollback in a trigger. Is this a proper way to rollback a newly inserted row? Or is there any better way to do it. (all procedures are built properly)

Comment: It doesn't work like this. If it did, you might insert 10 rows but find you only had 9 because your trigger silently undid one of them. But that `rollback` would undo all the inserts so far, along with any other uncommitted changes in your session, so you might have none. Then the remaining inserts might fail with FK violations if your trigger had rolled back the insert of a parent. The rows rolled back would be essentially random because a multi-row `insert` isn't necessarily in any particular order. This is the kind of reason why `commit` and `rollback` aren't allowed in triggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` inside of a `TRIGGER`, unless it's an autonomous transaction.

Inside your `TRIGGER`, you should do whatever logic you wish to apply, but if you reach an error condition, you should raise an application error, rather than `ROLLBACK`.  That should cause the `INSERT` statement that fired the `TRIGGER` to error, doing a statement level rollback, and return your transaction to the state it was just before you executed the INSERT.  At that point, you can evaluate the error, decide whether to rollback the entire transaction, or re-try the `INSERT`, or something else.

More on autonomous transactions:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#GUID-C0C61571-5175-400D-AEFC-FDBFE4F87188

More on statement-level rollback:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm#i8072